# Convert Custom String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, string.format

I have string which in the following format :130606082236. Now this needs to be converted into DateTime format as 2013-06-06 08:22:36,000. How do I create a custom format method and convert this ?

Comment: Google datetime.parseexact . Sorry for possible incorrect spelling, on a mobile browser.

Comment: How can you be sure that it is `2013` not `1913`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("130606082236", "yyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("130606082236", "yyMMddHHmmss", null);//new DateTime(2013, 06, 06, 08, 22, 36);
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToLongTimeString());
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss"));
```

Otherwords the Method: `DateTime.ParseExact` with Format `yyMMddHHmmss`

Format Specification available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)